# rewrite for uppercase and lowercase

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create clean url for pages on my site.

http://localhost/user.php?id=50&name=İSMAİL

This one works:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /user.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

It has special turkish characters and they are uppercase. So I want to redirect these to same page:

http://localhost/50/İSMAİL

http://localhost/50/ismail

Comment: This should be handled at form submission. When a simple `toLowerCase()` can fix the issue I see no reason of employing mod-rewrite which would check each and every request that ever comes and just hamper performance.

Comment: I think that you could let it as is and use ´[NC]´ flag

Answer (score 0):

Ravi is right, you need to normalise your DB data. You still store the name as entered by your user, but you create an additional column which has a normalised ‘slug’ version of the name. Try a [library like URLify](https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify) to do it for you.

Then, in the URLs you put in your own content, use the slug. If you get requests where the slug in the URL doesn't match that user id's, just redirect to to the correct id + slug URL..

```
RewriteRule ^([1-9]\d*)/([^/]*)$ user.php?id=$1&name=$2 [B,QSA,L]
```

In `user.php`, load the user only by `$_GET['id']` then compare the names.